# Foreign Key Relationship Between Columns of Table A and Rows of Table B?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

I have 2 tables - Table A and Table B. Table A is a simple table with rows and columns. The rows of Table B correspond to the columns of Table A.

### TableA

| id | timestamp | temperature | vibration | voltage | current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 474929 | 347 | -38.4 | 7.2 | 8.55 |
| 2 | 349857 | 472 | 84.4 | 1.4 | -0.54 |
| 3 | 398548 | 291 | -57.5 | -8.5 | 12.22 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

### TableB

| metric_name | min_limit | max_limit | threshold_value | units | abbreviation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| temperature | 220 | 400 | 340 | °F | temp |
| vibration | -100 | 90 | 85 | m/s | vib |
| voltage | -10 | 15 | 12 | V | volt |
| current | 5.00 | 15.00 | 20.00 | A | current |

I need to lookup a row in Table B based on a `TableB.metric_name` value that matches a column name from Table A.

Is this possible (I'm using Postgres and SQLAlchemy)?

Is this bad database design?

Comment: This is a bad database design.  Either both tables should have the same columns.  Or both should be key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the tables you designed does not give you this feature, you can use the primary key of tableA in tableB

Comment: I don't think this will work because there is no no mapping between the primary key from TableA to a row in TableB. There is however a 1:1 mapping between the column names in TableA and the rows of TableB.